# Names of the advisors and the candidate not aligned on the frontispiece

Tags: toptesi

Do you know why the names of the advisors and the candidate on the title page are not aligned?

```
\ateneo{xxxxxxx}
\facolta{Musica Elettronica}
\CorsoDiLaureaIn{Istituto di Alta Formazione Artistica}
\corsodilaurea{Musicale}
\corsodilaurea{Musicale}
\TesiDiLaurea{Diploma Accademico di II Livello in Musica Elettronica}
\titolo{xxxxxxxxxxx}
\sottotitolo{xxxxxxx}
\relatore{Prof.\ xxxxx}
\secondorelatore{Prof.\ xxxxx}
\candidato{Mxxx Mxxxx}
\logosede{images/logo}
\sedutadilaurea{xxxxx}
\frontespizio
```

[image: names of the realtors and the candidate not aligned in the frontispiece]

Answer (score 1):

To align the names of the Relatori and the Candidato you can use the class option `evenboxes`. This option is false by default to allow sufficient space to place signatures (2 for the supervisors vs 1 for the candidate).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
corpo=10pt,
stile=standard,
tipotesi=magistrale,
evenboxes
]{toptesi}

\begin{document}
\ateneo{xxxxxxx}
\facolta{Musica Elettronica}
\CorsoDiLaureaIn{Istituto di Alta Formazione Artistica}
\corsodilaurea{Musicale}
\corsodilaurea{Musicale}
\TesiDiLaurea{Diploma Accademico di II Livello in Musica Elettronica}
\titolo{xxxxxxxxxxx}
\sottotitolo{xxxxxxx}
\relatore{Prof.\ xxxxx}
\secondorelatore{Prof.\ xxxxx}
\candidato{Mxxx Mxxxx}
\logosede{example-image}
\sedutadilaurea{xxxxx}
\frontespizio
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]